# Is there any way to get private key in EVP_KEY structure from windows certstore?

Tags: windows, openssl, certificate, private-key

I tried to get private key from certstore using windows API(PFXExportCertStoreEx).

This API is able to export the CRYPT_DATA_BLOB from certstore for corresponding CERT_INDEX. But I need private key  in EVP_KEY structure , Since my application is using openssl API for SSL_CTX. So the exported structure CRYPT_DATA_BLOBit is not fit to the EVP_PKEY in SSL context(SSL_CTX).

Any help would be appreciated.

I am new to this windows certstore. If you need any  more info let me know.

Comment: Hello! Do you got it? I want the very same thing! If so, pleas, share with us!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CRYPT_DATA_BLOB dataBlob = {0};
if(PFXExportCertStoreEx(hStore, &dataBlob, password, NULL,
            EXPORT_PRIVATE_KEYS | REPORT_NOT_ABLE_TO_EXPORT_PRIVATE_KEY | REPORT_NO_PRIVATE_KEY))
{
    if (dataBlob.cbData > 0)
    {
        dataBlob.pbData = (BYTE*)malloc(dataBlob.cbData);
        if (PFXExportCertStoreEx(hSystemStore, &dataBlob, password.toStdWString().c_str(), NULL,
                    EXPORT_PRIVATE_KEYS | REPORT_NOT_ABLE_TO_EXPORT_PRIVATE_KEY | REPORT_NO_PRIVATE_KEY))
        {
            EVP_PKEY *pkey;
            X509 *cert;
            STACK_OF(X509) *ca = NULL;
            PKCS12 *p12;
            int i;
            CRYPTO_malloc_init();
            OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
            SSLeay_add_all_algorithms();
            ERR_load_crypto_strings();

            BIO* input = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)dataBlob.pbData, dataBlob.cbData);
            p12 = d2i_PKCS12_bio(input, NULL);

            PKCS12_parse(p12, password.toStdString().c_str(), &pkey, &cert, &ca);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the above code might be useful. It worked for me, but you need to use OpenSSL API @Carlos.