# Why does OpenSSL throw error as I'm trying to get raw private key?

Tags: c++, qt, openssl

```
EVP_PKEY * privKey = generate_key();

if (privKey == NULL){
   qDebug() << "NULL PRIVATE KEY";
   exit(-1);
}
X509 * certif = generate_x509(privKey);
if (certif == NULL){
   qDebug() << "NULL CERT";
   exit(-1);
}
BIO* bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());

if (!PEM_write_bio_X509(bio, certif)){
   qDebug() << "NULL RETURNED BY PEM_write_bio_x509";
    exit(-1);
}
std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf;
BUF_MEM* biostruct;
BIO_get_mem_ptr(bio, &biostruct);
buf = std::make_unique<char[]>(biostruct->length);
if (static_cast<size_t>(BIO_read(bio, buf.get(), biostruct->length)) != biostruct->length){
   qDebug() << "Houston, we have some problems";
   exit(-1);
}

size_t lengthOfPrivateKey = 0;
//    uint32_t* privkey = new uint32_t[lengthOfPrivateKey];

EVP_PKEY_get_raw_private_key(privKey, NULL, &lengthOfPrivateKey);
if (lengthOfPrivateKey == 0){
   qDebug() << "Private key is 0";
   exit(-1);
}
std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> prKey(new unsigned char[lengthOfPrivateKey]);
if (!EVP_PKEY_get_raw_private_key(privKey, prKey.get(), &lengthOfPrivateKey)){
    qDebug() << "Unable to get private key";
    exit(-1);
}
size_t lengthOfPublicKey = 0;
EVP_PKEY_get_raw_public_key(privKey, NULL, &lengthOfPublicKey);
if (lengthOfPublicKey == 0){
   qDebug() << "Public key is 0";
   exit(-1);
}
std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> pubKey(new unsigned char[lengthOfPublicKey]);
if (!EVP_PKEY_get_raw_public_key(privKey, pubKey.get(), &lengthOfPublicKey)){
    qDebug() << "Unable to get public key";
    exit(-1);
}
```

Does anyone know what I can do to get my private key?

When I am calling my program, it throws "Private key is 0" error message. After debugging with GDB, I found that buf is somehow equal to a single char ("-"), whilst certificate and key are generating as they are supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

`EVP_PKEY_get_raw_private_key()` applicable only to certain algorithms, as you may read in the official documentation https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/EVP_PKEY_get_raw_private_key.html:

```
...
Currently this is: EVP_PKEY_HMAC, EVP_PKEY_POLY1305, EVP_PKEY_SIPHASH, EVP_PKEY_X25519, EVP_PKEY_ED25519, EVP_PKEY_X448 or EVP_PKEY_ED448.
...
```

Comment: Thanx! And how can RSA private/public key?

Comment: It depends on which format you need to obtain your key. Maybe this could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40909071/is-there-any-way-to-get-private-key-in-evp-key-structure-from-windows-certstore

Comment: I need to get them in char* (or unsigned char*) format in order to pass to the QSslKey constructor and initialize server. Actually, I only need private key and public key is quite unnecessary.